# Problem with import/export using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on something in codesandbox.io and trying to get react-router-dom working, but I'm getting the following error and can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

> Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Home</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

User Error: I was just accepting whatever version codesandbox gave which was 6.*.* when I dropped to 5.3.3 all is well.